# "No cached version... available for offline mode."

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I received an error message while building a new Hello World project in Android Studio:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'MyApplication2'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.1.
     Required by:
         :MyApplication2:unspecified
      > No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.1 available for offline mode.

BUILD FAILED
```

Android Studio version: 0.5.2

Gradle version: 0.9.1

I'm using a proxy connection to Internet.

Comment: Have you tried configuring your Android Studio to use the proxy server. You may want to see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18443208/androidstudio-gradle-proxy

Comment: Describe your "proxy connection to the internet". Clearly the initial cache isnt done as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20746071/failed-to-build-android-hello-world-application-in-offline-mode

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but now I'm getting an another problem.

Failed to refresh Gradle project 'My Application 2'
           Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/0.9.1/gradle-0.9.1.pom'. Received status code 500 from server: Internal Server Error
           Enable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project

As said above comments, I have configured the proxy settings in the Android Studio.

Answer (score 218):

With the new Android Studio 3.6 to toggle Gradle's offline mode go to `View` > `Tool Windows` > `Gradle` from the menu bar and toggle the value of Offline Mode that is near the top of the Gradle window.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This still didnt worked for me. Android version 3.6.3 and gradle version 5.6.4

Comment: This answer was objective. It worked for me. Thank's

Comment: It's working. Clean and Rebuild your project.

Answer (score 206):

Had the same error after updating Android Studio today. For me, it wasn't a matter of proxy settings:

1. Uncheck "Offline work" in Android Studio 0.6.0:

   **File->Settings->Gradle->Global Gradle Settings**

   or in OSX:

   **Preferences->Gradle->Global Gradle Setting**

   or in more recent versions:

   **File->Settings->Build, Execution, Deployment->Build tools->Gradle**
2. Resync the project, for example by restarting the Android Studio
3. Once synced, you can check the option again to work offline.

(Only tested in Gradle version 0.11... and Android Studio version 0.6.0 Preview)

**EDIT :** Added paths for different versions/platforms (as mentioned by **John Ballinger** and **The_Martian**). Not yet verified.

Comment: ON OSX: Uncheck "Offline work" in Android Studio >Preferences>Gradle>Global Gradle Settings

Comment: Android Studio will start downloading files after that, so probably a good idea to wait till it finishes (v0.8.1).

Comment: I was  getting this error when I tried to include Crashlytics and this solution worked perfectly.

Comment: Offline work is rather located in File->Settings->Build, Execution, Deployment->Build tools->Gradle and not in the path you mentioned.

Comment: @friedrich  I have a question: I copy the same version  jar into dir ./gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1, and use offline mode also happen this error. what different once synced,and then use offline again

Comment: These paths do not exist for android studio 4. I can't find how to toggle offline mode in android studio 4. I turned it on in android studio 3.6 and upgraded to 4.0 and I am lost now

Comment: I tried File->Settings->Build, Execution, Deployment->Build tools->Gradle but I don't see any off line check box

Answer (score 64):

Please follow below steps :

1.Open Your project.

2.Go to the Left side of the Gradle button.

3.Look at below image.

[image]

4.Click button above image show.

5.if this type of view you are not in offline mode.

6.Go to Build and rebuild the project.

All above point is work for me.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NRrFNXw-tb0

Video solution of a problem

Comment: In my Android Studio the Gradle Tab was on the right side.

Comment: Also in here, are all your answers copy of previous answers?

Answer (score 42):

Just happened to me after upgrading to Android Studio 3.1. The Offline Work checkbox was unchecked, so no luck there.

I went to `Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler` and the `Command-line Options` textfield contained `--offline`, so I just deleted that and everything worked.

[image: setting screenshot]

Comment: Worked for me too, but I wonder, does this mean I can't later build offline or?

Comment: This is the correct answer! Unchecking offline mode didn't help (it was already unchecked), but this did.

Comment: in my case was a command-line options, take a look into it https://stackoverflow.com/a/59376069/2238515

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me. I was stucked at 'Downloading kotlin-util-stdlib' for 2 hours.

Answer (score 24):

I had same error...Please Uncheck the offline work in Settings.

***File => Settings => Build, Execution, Deployment => Build Tools => Gradle => Offline Work***

After Gradle Sync Finished, Please **Restart Your Android Studio.**

Answer (score 6):

[image]

1. click on right second one image .
2. file -> invalidate and Restart .

It will work for me please try !!!

Answer (score 4):

For mac, Uncheck `Offline Work` from `Preference -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle -> Global Gradle Settings`

tip: `cmd`+`,` to open `Preference` via shortcut key

Answer (score 1):

Since you mention you have a proxy connection I will tell you what worked for me:
I went to properties (as friedrich mentioned) ensuring the Offline Work was unchecked.
I opened up the gradle.properties file in the IDE and added my proxy settings.  Here's a generic version:

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=www.somehost.org
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.http.proxyUser=userid
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=password
systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=*.nonproxyrepos.com|localhost
```

Then at the top of the properties file in the IDE there was a "Try Again" link which I clicked. That did it.

Answer (score 1):

**New Solution** (Due to the redoing of Android Studio)

File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> **Compliler**

In the line **Command-line Options** delete: **--offline**

Answer (score 0):

In my case I get the same error title **could not resolve all dependencies for configuration**

However suberror said, it was due to a linting jar not loaded with its url given saying status 502 received, I ran the deployment command again, this time it succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

For new UI, click the icon cloud to enable/disable offline mode.

[image]