# How to successfully sync in Android Studio?

Tags: android, gradle

Version Info:

Android Studio -- 0.8.0

Gradle -- 2.0

Issue: When open Android Studio, the following information displays, hence it is not able to run the program.

Error:No cached version listing for com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+ available for offline mode.

Answer (score 1):

From : https://stackoverflow.com/a/24106285/1239966

1. Uncheck "Offline work" in File>Settings>Gradle>Global Gradle Settings
2. Resync the project, for example by restarting the Android Studio
3. Once synced, you can check the option again to work offline.

Comment: If uncheck "Offline Work", and resync the project, the following message comes out                                       <Error:Connection timed out: connect. If you are behind an HTTP proxy, please configure the proxy settings either in IDE or Gradle.>

Comment: This answer is correct.. If you also have proxy issues, that's a different issue.