# Whats wrong with my Android studio's gradle?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

```
Error:No cached version of com.android.databinding:compilerCommon:1.0-rc5 available for offline mode.
```

Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project

even in the preview part , there is no phone screen.

Comment: The error message suggests that you do something...

Comment: simply your gradle version in `build.gradle` is not the same as your local copy of gradle tool

Comment: Try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22607661/no-cached-version-of-com-android-tools-buildgradle0-9-1-available-for-offline

Answer (score 0):

Did you change settings in Android Studio to work offline?
Change them back to online, and synchronise gradle.

After synchronising you can set Android Studio back to offline again!

You can't synch gradle, when you are working offline.

Comment: Yes that should be the problem , i changed it to offline, but could you tell me how can i change it to online again? Thank u

Comment: @faramarz Change to online again by turning off offline mode.

Comment: Found it, but it was still online mode , should find another solution,