# Gradle dependency compile issues (Android Studio 3.0.1)

Tags: java, android

I am using android studio 3.0.1 , Gradle cannot resolve dependencies. error. No cached version available. I have inculded both the mavenCentral() and google() within repositories section of module level gradle. But still, gradle, cannot resolve dependencies ,especially those that are present in mavenCentral().

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22607661/no-cached-version-of-com-android-tools-buildgradle0-9-1-available-for-offline)

Comment: Make sure Offline Mode is off.