# Failed to generate apk from Android studio 3.1.1

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, android-studio-3.1

When I try to generate a signed APK, I found this issue :

> 10:58 Generate Signed APK: Errors while building APK. You can find the errors in the 'Messages' view.
>   No cached version of com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:26.1.1 available for offline mode.

this is my android studio details :

```
Android Studio 3.1.1
Build #AI-173.4697961, built on April 4, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b02 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0
```

this block for signing the apk :

```
  buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.releaseconfig
    }
    debug {

        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

}  signingConfigs {
    releaseconfig {
        keyAlias 'release_key'
        keyPassword 'xxxxx'
        storeFile file('xxxxxx)
        storePassword 'xxxx'
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22607661/no-cached-version-of-com-android-tools-buildgradle0-9-1-available-for-offline?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa Please check this

Comment: try this delete `.gradle` folder from your project and rebuild the project and generate apk file.

Answer (score 20):

Per the [Android Studio docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/index.html), your top-level `build.gradle` ought to have the `google()` repository added. Be sure to add it to the `repositories` under `buildscript` AND `allprojects`.

The latter one is what I missed the first time I edited this today after upgrading and that led directly to a `Could not find com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:26.1.1.` when I tried to build a release APK.

Comment: I wish I could help - it may be there are other issues with this release that are complicating matters.

Answer (score 4):

Solved (works for me) changing gradle version in the project build.gradle:

From this

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1'
```

to this

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
```

Comment: Does not work, got new error like this: "Expected a name but was STRING at line 1 column 99 path $[0].apkInfo.versionName"

Comment: @BabulMirdha take a look here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49809977/expected-a-name-but-was-string-at-line-1-column-99-path-0-apkinfo-versionname

Comment: This worked for me. This was even highlighted in Android Studio as a suggested thing to change. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think this version required updated libs and gradle.
try to change to `compileSdkVersion 27` and libaries as.

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
```

and gradle ver,

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Setting debug to True in release mode though `debuggable` should be set to false in release APK but currently this is the solution i get.

```
release {
            debuggable true
        }
```

**Update**

Adding the following code in gradle to make it work

```
lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler to see if Command-line Options contains `--offline` See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49586824/404597).

Comment: This was it! 
I did not think about the command line options set

Answer (score 0):

please open your AndroidStudio and find click `File` and then find `settings`.

second you click `compiler` and then find `Command-line Options:` `remove --offline`

Answer (score 0):

```
lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
}
```

//add this on gradle file inside android tag

Answer (score 0):

Please use **[Analyze > Inspect Code](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint#manuallyRunInspections)** to inspect your code

If your app could be compiled and running just fine but you failed to generate sign APK. For me, after running inspection it shows me a few errors in my code. I fixed all those errors then I could build sign APK just fine. Check this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51363161/10078629) for more option to fix this