# Expected a name but was STRING at line 1 column 99 path $[0].apkInfo.versionName

Tags: android, gradle

I upgraded to gradle to 3.1.1 but now i want to change again to 3.0.1 but after changing to 3.0.1 i am getting this error

> Expected a name but was STRING at line 1 column 99 path $[0].apkInfo.versionName

I was using 3.0.1 before and it was working perfectly but i changed after android studio update.

The error is only coming when generating signed apk.

**Project Gradle**

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

 allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**App gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.smiles.smartstuddy"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 4
    versionName "1.1"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:27.1.1'
compile 'com.github.lzyzsd:circleprogress:1.2.1'
compile 'dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:+'
implementation files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
compile 'es.voghdev.pdfviewpager:library:1.0.3'
 }
```

Answer (score 33):

Check the **release** folder where the .apk is going to be generated. If there is any existing .apk or .json files, then delete or move them to another location. Try generating your signed apk again and you should be successful.

Comment: Specifically deleting output.json should be enough.

Comment: also if you're directly building it into an emulator or device, deleting an already installed version could help

Comment: For me I had to delete also lint-results-release-fatal in report folder.

Answer (score 28):

I was getting the same error in the same use case and what fixed it for me was to clean and rebuild the project.

Comment: What did work was to change the output dir... I don't know why, but if it helps the original output dir was shared with another app (same generation folder).

Comment: This worked for me. It solved my error `Expected a name but was STRING at line 1 column 108 path $[0].apkInfo.versionName`

Comment: Clean and rebuild did not work, has anyone solved this issue?

Comment: @Teriblus do you mean changing the folder in which gets stored the signed APKs; QA, PROD?

Comment: I also had to switch flavours to get it to work.  (I also switched git branches from Gradle 4.4 to 4.1 then it started breaking. Probably didn't help)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code into the app **build.gradle** file.

```
lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried all previous suggestion with no success.
After using "File/Invalidate Caches/restart" the problem was solved.