# Failed to generate signed .apk

Tags: android

After update to android 3.1.1 i get this error when i try to generate signed apk:

```
Could not find com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:26.1.1.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/C:/Users/Me/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.1/lint-gradle-26.1.1.pom
    file:/C:/Users/Me/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.1/lint-gradle-26.1.1.jar
    file:/C:/Users/Me/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.1/lint-gradle-26.1.1.pom
    file:/C:/Users/Me/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.1/lint-gradle-26.1.1.jar
    file:/C:/Users/Me/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.1/lint-gradle-26.1.1.pom
    file:/C:/Users/Me/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.1/lint-gradle-26.1.1.jar
```

https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.1/lint-gradle-26.1.1.pom
        https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.1/lint-gradle-26.1.1.jar

Required by:
        project :app

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to generate apk from Android studio 3.1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49751066/failed-to-generate-apk-from-android-studio-3-1-1)

Comment: Install and rebuild the project

Answer (score 4):

In my case, just adding google() repository for all projects config worked:

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I was getting the same error. I was able to generate the APK, **but not the signed APK**.

To be able to generate the signed APK, I've started by separating `/Application/build.grade` in two files, according to https://developer.android.com/studio/build/index.html. Previously I was using just `/Application/build.grade` with and empty `/build.gradle` file.

My `/build.gradle` looks like:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

The `/Application/build.grade` is

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    api fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    api 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1'
    api 'com.android.support:support-v13:24.1.1'
    api 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.1.1'
    api 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    api 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
    api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:10.0.0'
    api 'com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.10'
}

List<String> dirs = ['main', 'common', 'template'] 

android {
    // compileSdkVersion 24
    compileSdkVersion 26
    // buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        versionCode 260
        versionName "2.60"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 24
        applicationId "com.activeng.bluetoothlegatt"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile rootProject.file('../keystore.jks')
            keyAlias 'activengkey'
            keyPassword 'xxxxxxx'
            storePassword 'xxxxxxx'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            dirs.each { dir ->
                java.srcDirs "src/${dir}/java"
                res.srcDirs "src/${dir}/res"
            }
        }
        androidTest.setRoot('tests')
        androidTest.java.srcDirs = ['tests/src']

    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

}
```

I've done a "Sync now" after changing the files, and I was able to generate the signed APK again.

Answer (score 0):

So, I figure it out

changing gradle version in the project build.gradle:
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1'
to 
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'

after that I did Sync now from upper right corner, Clean Project, Rebuild Project and then it generated the sign apk.

But changing the version back to 3.1.1 I got the same error:
Could not find com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:26.1.1.

It turns out, that if I DON’T allow Android Studio 3.1.1 to update to Android Gradle plugin to version 3.1.1 and Gradle to version 4.4. and to Android SDK Build Tools 27.0.3 then I can build the Release version without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me after adding "google()" under allprojects.repositories. Like this

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```