# While generating APK, It's showing build failed, this is the error message

Tags: android

While generating APK, It's showing build failed, this is the error message :

```
    Could not find com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:26.1.1.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/C:/Users/Abde/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.1/lint-gradle-26.1.1.pom
    file:/C:/Users/Abde/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.1/lint-gradle-26.1.1.jar
    file:/C:/Users/Abde/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.1/lint-gradle-26.1.1.pom
    file:/C:/Users/Abde/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.1/lint-gradle-26.1.1.jar
    file:/C:/Users/Abde/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.1/lint-gradle-26.1.1.pom
    file:/C:/Users/Abde/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.1/lint-gradle-26.1.1.jar
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.1/lint-gradle-26.1.1.pom
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.1/lint-gradle-26.1.1.jar
Required by:
    project :app
```

this is build gradl file (app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "appli.myapp.app"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.1"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
}
```

this is a build gradle (project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I am a beginner on android studio :/, I made several times "clean" but it does not work unfortunately
Help me please Thank you

Comment: this is a build gradle (project)
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

Comment: Could you edit your question and add the code snipped you posted in the comment into the question itself and correctly formatted so it's easier to read.

Comment: @JudeFernandes I have this error :/ 
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Comment: Just add a little more text to describe your situation and stackoverflow should let you through.

Comment: @JudeFernandes ok friend, thank you, it worked

Answer (score 1):

First try disabling AS offline mode

> Go to File -> Settings.
>
> And open the 'Build,Execution,Deployment',Then open the 'Build Tools'
>   -> 'Gradle'.
>
> Then uncheck "Offline work" on the right.
>
> Click the 'OK' button.
>
> Then Rebuild the Project.
>
> For Mac go to AndroidStudio -> Preferences, rest is same.

If this does not work then try this. According to this [reference question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49767383/6891563)

> Per the [Android Studio docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/) , your top-level build.gradle ought
>   to have the google() repository added. Be sure to add it to the
>   repositories under buildscript AND allprojects.
>
> The latter one is what I missed the first time I edited this today
>   after upgrading and that led directly to a Could not find
>   com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:26.1.1. when I tried to build a
>   release APK.

Add the google() in your project level build.gradle like this

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you my friend, but it does not work,the "offline work" is uncheck :/

Comment: try other one dude

Comment: for the second method, the instructions I must integrate them into the gradle (app) or project ?
thanks friend

Comment: Edited answer for you dude

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you might be missing a few sdk files, goto the sdk manager and update to latest versions and upgrade your appcompat versions to `27.1.1`, update your target sdk to 27 as well as compile sdk and use `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'` for that you will also need to use this in your `gradle-wrapper.properties` `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip`