# Configure Android Gradle gradle-core-3.1.4.jar plugin in build.gradle in offline mode

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
        jcenter { url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/" }
        google()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
        jcenter { url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/" }
        google()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
}
```

Because of network restrictions, i cannot sync gradle and trying to make it completely offline. I have enabled offline mode for gradle. After executing it says **No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4 available for offline mode.**

How can i configure gradle-core-3.4.jar android gradle plugin in offline case ?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Try this [No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.1 available for offline mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22607661/no-cached-version-of-com-android-tools-buildgradle0-9-1-available-for-offline)

Comment: Tried. It says you have to sync in online mode atleast once so that it get cached. I cant sync once also in my case because of network restrictions in my organizations. I completely want to configure gradle-core-3.4.jar from first sync itself in offline mode.