# YouTubePlayerFragment hide rotate loading

Tags: android, android-fragments, youtube-api, loading, android-youtube-api

I need to prevent any UI appear on youtube player, even the rotate loading that appears before starting the video.
I use this line to prevent any control

```
youTubePlayer.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.CHROMELESS);
```

but I can't find any way to hide the rotate loading!!!

Answer (score 1):

I have developed an open source YouTube player library ([android-youtube-player](https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player)), you can use it's UI customization APIs to create your own UI for it. You can read more [here](https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player#create-your-own-custom-ui) in the doc.

Comment: yes, it seems like a great job. thank you
but when I try to download it, get me this error while synchronizing the gradle

"  Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer:core:8.0.1.   "
when i click show details get this

"   Required by:
    project :app
 > No cached version of com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer:core:8.0.1 available for offline mode."

Comment: @nagwaredaa Does your Android Studio have access to the internet?

Comment: it works finally. the problem in an android studio, I solve it like this >>> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22607661/no-cached-version-of-com-android-tools-buildgradle0-9-1-available-for-offline

Comment: I can not hide the loading view also using this library

Answer (score 0):

You can try to host the video then use API where you can customize your media player.

Use:

- [JW player](http://www.jwplayer.com/)
- [Flow Player](https://flowplayer.org/docs/cuepoints.html)

Or

Try to manipulate the background of your  container using CSS. Use property *`opacity`* to add transparency to the background of your element. Set it to **0** for default, then set it to **1** once it start playing.

Comment: Thanks, @jess my project is an Android application.your answer dose not seems to be for the android application. or I don't understand