# Android Studio Gradle Showing No Cached Version available

Tags: android-studio, caching

I have just updated to Android Studio 3.1.4 and now it is showing
"No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4 available for offline mode"
And if I turn off offline mode it is showing another error in loading dl.google.com/.... 
 I want to run Android studio without Internet Connectivity.
How to solve this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.1 available for offline mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22607661/no-cached-version-of-com-android-tools-buildgradle0-9-1-available-for-offline)

Answer (score 0):

You probably checked the offline mode in:

`File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle`.

Uncheck the option `Offline work` and you'll be good to go.

**Edit:**

In fact, you’ll need to get connected to the internet for the first time downloading the dependencies-packages-meta files and etc. Then after, you’ll be able to use Android Studio offline if you don’t change the `Build.gradle`.

Comment: Would you add the whole error in the question? thanks.

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: Updated the answer. Explained why you need to get connected to the internet.