# Android Studio 3.2 - "Waiting for build to finish" & could not download gradle.jar

Tags: java, android, gradle

Im currently facing a few issues using android studio 3.2.

The first of which is that after setting up my first project, "Waiting for build to finish" appears under activity_main.xml.

After reading through a few forums, i synced with gradle however another error appears - "Could not download gradle.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1): No cached version available for offline mode"

I am unsure now how to fix this, i am connected to the internet and have not manually entered offline mode.

Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.1 available for offline mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22607661/no-cached-version-of-com-android-tools-buildgradle0-9-1-available-for-offline)

Answer (score 0):

Check your strings.xml located in res/values/string.xml. There might be missing values or translatable must not been set false. Update your string.xml as shown

**set translatable="false"**

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name" translatable="false">Your Title</string>

<!-- TODO: Remove or change this placeholder text -->
<string name="hello_blank_fragment" translatable="false">Hello blank fragment</string>
<string name="renewal" translatable="false">Renewal</string>
```

This worked for me hope it works for you too.