# Gradle Build Sync Failed In Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I am building an app in android studio, but the app refuse to sync.

I have added org.gradle.jvmargs=-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true to the gradle.properties file.

I have navigated to:

File -> Sync Project with Gradle Files,

Build -> Rebuild Project, I have also restarted android studio. Yet all to no avail.
It's showing me these three errors:

1) `Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.`

2) `Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0.`

3) `Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0 available for offline mode.`

How can solve this error? Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22607661/no-cached-version-available-for-offline-mode

Comment: Uncheck the offline work in Settings